# What the difference between deadlock avoidance and deadlock prevention?

Tags: multithreading

I have heard both of these terms used, are they the same thing or different things?

Comment: Is this like the difference between tax avoidance and tax ... err ...  prevention?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You could look at it as:

Avoid: Don't share resources across processes / mulitple threads

Prevent: When accsessing shared resources, use a semaphore.  If locking multiple semaphores, be sure to unlock in the reverse order of locking.  Always be sure to handle errors within the critical sections so the semaphore is released under all conditions.

Comment: This explanation is not complete and correct. Deadlock avoidance is about being in a safe state always while prevention is not letting at least one of the 4 characteristics of the  deadlock fail all the time.

Answer (score 32):

**Deadlock:**

A deadlock is a situation where two or more competing actions are each waiting for the other to finish, and thus neither ever does. It can also be defined as a set of blocked processes each holding a resource and waiting to acquire a resource held by another process in the set.

For example if there is a system with two disk drives. If there are two processes P1 and P2 each hold one disk drive and each needs the other one, then the situation of deadlock occurs.
The following conditions will be held simultaneously in case of deadlock:

• Mutual exclusion:  only one process at a time can use a resource

• Hold and wait:  a process holding at least one resource is waiting to acquire additional resources held by other processes

• No preemption:  a resource can be released only voluntarily by the process holding it, after that process has completed its task

• Circular wait:  there exists a set {P0, P1, …, Pn} of waiting processes such that P0 is waiting for a resource that is held by P1, P1 is waiting for a resource that is held by P2, …, Pn–1 is waiting for a resource that is held by Pn, and Pn is waiting for a resource that is held by P0.

Differences between Deadlock prevention, avoidance and detection are as follows:

**Prevention**:

• The goal is to ensure that at least one of the necessary conditions for deadlock can never hold.

• Deadlock prevention is often impossible to implement.

• The system does not require additional a priori information regarding the overall potential use of each resource for each process.

• In order for the system to prevent the deadlock condition it does not need to know all the details of all resources in existence, available and requested.

• Deadlock prevention techniques include non-blocking synchronization algorithms, serializing tokens, Dijkstra's algorithm etc.

• Resource allocation strategy for deadlock prevention is conservative, it under commits the resources.

• All resources are requested at once.

• In some cases preempts more than often necessary.

**Avoidance:**

• The goal for deadlock avoidance is to the system must not enter an unsafe state.

• Deadlock avoidance is often impossible to implement.

• The system requires additional a priori information regarding the overall potential use of each resource for each process.

• In order for the system to be able to figure out whether the next state will be safe or unsafe, it must know in advance at any time the number and type of all resources in existence, available, and requested.

• Deadlock avoidance techniques include Banker’s algorithm, Wait/Die, Wound/Wait etc.

• Resource allocation strategy for deadlock avoidance selects midway between that of detection and prevention.

• Needs to be manipulated until at least one safe path is found.

• There is no preemption.

**Detection:**

• The goal is to detect the deadlock after it occurs or before it occurs.

• Detecting the possibility of a deadlock before it occurs is much more difficult and is, in fact, generally undecidable. However, in specific environments, using specific means of locking resources, deadlock detection may be decidable.

• The system does not requires additional a priori information regarding the overall potential use of each resource for each process in all cases.

• In order for the system to detect the deadlock condition it does not need to know all the details of all resources in existence, available and requested.

• A deadlock detection technique includes, but is not limited to, Model checking. This approach constructs a Finite State-model on which it performs a progress analysis and finds all possible terminal sets in the model.

• Resource allocation strategy for deadlock detection is very liberal. Resources are granted as requested.

• Needs to be invoked periodically to test for deadlock.

• Preemption is seen.

Answer (score 4):

Deadlock avoidance: means, whenever a request is made for a particular resource by a particular process, you look at the available resources, if the future resource needs for  process's already in use resources, determine the possibility of a deadlock in case the resource is granted. If possible, don't grant the resource, if not possible then grant the resource.

Deadlock prevention: make sure that at least one of the condition for deadlock to occur is not fulfilled at anytime. This can be achieved in the way resources are requested and granted in the system.

Answer (score 3):

1) Prevention: structure the system in such a way that one of the deadlock conditions is negated

2) Detection and recovery: let deadlocks occur, detect them and take
   action

3) Avoidance: 
           -don’t start processes whose requests may cause a deadlock 
           -don’t grant requests which may cause a deadlock

Answer (score 1):

For a deadlock to occur the below four conditions should occur simultaneously

1. Mutual Exclusion: At least one resource must be held in a non sharable mode. Another process requesting this resource must wait.
2. Hold and Wait: A process holds a resource and waits for resources held by another process
3. No Preemption: Resources cannot be released unless the process completes its task
4. Circular Wait: Set of processes {P0, P1, ... Pn} must exist such that P0 is waiting for resources held by P1, P1 waiting on resources held by P2, Pn is waiting on resources held by P0.

Deadlock prevention: We can prevent a deadlock by ensuring that at least one of the condition never holds.

Deadlock avoidance: System can avoid a deadlock by ensuring that the system is always in a safe state. A safe state is when there is a safe sequence of processes.
For ex: Let P1, P2, P3 be 3 processes. The sequence <P2, P1, P3> is called a safe sequence if the resource requests of P2 can be satisfied with the resources P2 currently has and the resources that system has. Next, P1 resource requests should be satisfied by the resources held by P2 and the system resources. Similarly for P3 the request should be satisfied by the resources held by P2, P1 and the system resources.
Bankers algorithm is an avoidance algorithm.

If a system doesn't ensure either a prevention or avoidance then there should be a mechanism to detect the break the lockdown by killing a process.